# Monads which are monoidal and opmonoidal

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, terminology, monoidal-categories, monads

Do monads which are monoidal and opmonoidal have a name? (Bimonoidal?) In case they have already been studied, who can point me to a reference?

More in detail. Let $(C,\otimes)$ be a symmetric (or braided) monoidal category. Let $(T,\eta,\mu)$ be a monad on $C$ such that:

1. $T:C\to C$ is a [bilax monoidal functor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/bilax+monoidal+functor) (compatible lax and colax monoidal structure);
2. $\eta,\mu$ are [monoidal natural transformations](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+natural+transformation) (commute with unit and multiplication);
3. $\eta,\mu$ are also op-monoidal natural transformation (commute with the counit and comultiplication).

In other words, $T$ is a monad *in* the 2-category of categories, bilax monoidal functors, and (bi)monoidal natural transformations (meaning monoidal and opmonoidal).

What is the standard terminology? What would be a reference?